# jQuery: if string matches one of these href's

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, href

I have this var in my code:

```
var href = $(this).attr('href'),
str = href.split('/').slice(-2,-1)[0];
```

How do I check if 'images', 'images-2' or 'images-3'
matches the 'href' string, then do something..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if href.match(/images(-[23])?/){
    doStuf();
}
```

should do the trick.

Comment: I'd make that a non-capturing group (?:) though. But that's the correct regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this:
http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

You can have something like:
$('[href^="images"]')

Edit:
You can also make your own selectors if you want to.
http://dpatrickcaldwell.blogspot.com/2010/03/custom-jquery-selector-for-external-and.html

James Padolsey has already written one that could work for you.
http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/

Comment: AFAICT, the OP doesn't know that the href will start with images, just that it will contain images. jQuery selector is a good way to go though if he knows enough about it to go that way.

Comment: jxpx777, I agree, but I don't know that it means you shouldn't use what's there.  The ~= is the contains selector.  It'd also work in this case if the name doesn't start with image.

Edit:
Evidently, enter doesn't do what I think it does in these input boxes :).

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/

Comment: The other thing is that it doesn't allow to limit to just images, images-2, images-3. `~= images` would still capture images-12, which a strict reading of the OP would deem unacceptable.

Comment: Perhaps, but if that were the case, I'd say you'd need a pretty good reason to do it via javascript at all instead of just adding a class and using CSS.  My guess is that the op is looking for a way of matching patterns in the jquery selector.  It may not be the case.  I'm just putting the information out there.  If you feel like my answer doesn't add value, feel free to downvote.  I'm just tryin' to help.

Comment: I would have been more clear if I had known at the time. It's 'images' in sequence, so in this case, it works perfectly if it catches 'images-12', but thanks for letting me know.